# ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC - Sort a string with range of date

Tags: c#, date, asp.net-core-mvc

I think I am coming closer to what I want but think I could use some help.

What I found out was if I do `order.by(x => x.Datum)` the date gets sorted despite being a string by the format `yyyy/MM/dd` so far so good, now I decided to extend the string to a daterange, like so: `dd/MM/yyyy-dd/mm/yyyy`.

From my point of understanding, I can also convert the string to a datetime object with `DateTime.ParseExact` but get the following error:

> FormatException: DateTime pattern 'd' appears more than once with different values

Is it not possible to store a date range in a `datetime` object?

```
public IActionResult Termin() //Diese Methode zeigt die Termine an.
{
    var termin = _context.Termin
                         .Select(x => new ViewModelExposeTermin
                                          {
                                              Id = x.Id,    
                                              Name = x.Name,    
                                              Ort  = x.Ort,
                                              Datum = x.Datum,
                                              Uhrzeit = x.Uhrzeit
                                          })
                         .ToList()
                         .OrderBy(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Datum, "dd/MM/yyyy-dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));

    return View(termin);
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve? You have date value stored in `dd/MM/yyyy-dd/mm/yyyy` format in `x.Datum` column?

Comment: you need to split the string on the '-' character and parse each pat separately

Comment: You can't parse a _single_ `DateTime` object that has the date, month, and year information twice. ParseExact (and DateTimes) can't be used for ranges.

Comment: @Chetan - exactly the date value is stored as you wrote in the database

Comment: @gunr2171 Okay.. soo can I use Parse?

Comment: You do what pm100 told you, you use the Parse methods to parse _one_ DateTime's data at a time.

Comment: @gunr2171 So, I split it with "system.split" ? - but this can all still be done in one line?

Comment: Try it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0

Comment: You _absolutely_ should not be storing a data range like you're doing _as a single column_ in a table. Make them separate columns.

Comment: @gunr2171 Alright, I will change my models then.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that sql has a data-range like type, instead you could use 2 datetime fields.

```cs
public class TerminDatabaseModel
{
    /*
     * Some other properties
     */
    
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create your own custom `DateTimeRange` value type, it should implements `IComparer<DateTimeRange>` in order to be used in `OrderBy` by Linq.

```cs
public readonly struct DateTimeRange : IComparer<DateTimeRange>
{
    public DateTimeRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; }
    public DateTime End { get; }
    public TimeSpan Duration => Start - End;
    
    // comparing implementation
    public int Compare(DateTimeRange x, DateTimeRange y)
    {
        return x.Duration.CompareTo(y.Duration);
    }

    /*
     * Other stuff
     */
}
```

and add it to your ViewModel

```cs
public class ViewModelExposeTermin
{
    /*
     * Some other properties
     */
    
    public DateTimeRange Datum { get; init; }
}
```

Finally, map the `DateTime` fields to the `DateTimeRange` field with

```cs
var termin = _context.Termin
        .Select(x => new ViewModelExposeTermin
        {
            Id = x.Id,    
            Name = x.Name,    
            Ort  = x.Ort,
            Datum = new DateTimeRange(x.StartDateTime, x.EndDateTime),
            Uhrzeit = x.Uhrzeit
        })
        .ToList()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Datum);

    return View(termin);
```

## **Note**

The order take place **after** the data are retrieved from the database. To perform the sort inside the query, you have to use EF's `OrderBy` before fetching with `ToList`